# Looking for inspiration for an oddly specific bash script

Tags: linux, bash, loops, submission

I am working on a little variant of a job submission file. Please bear with me.

The general structure of the submission files is:

```
 #job run time
 #cores
 #memory

execute program on dir1/input &

execute program on dir2/input &

...

execute program on dir6/input 
exit
```

Each submission file contains 6 directories because that is the optimal way to split the number of cores/mem we have on our computer. The problem is that if one calculation completes, then only five calculations are running, but I still have to pay the same # of SUs to our supercomputer as if I were running the full set of six.

I have several hundred of such input directories so I usually made a few hundred of these submission files with updated directory numbers. I made a small program that lists me which directories started getting operated on but could not complete before the 96 hours were up and which have not been run at all (findincompletefolders.sh). Let's say that the list is contained in a text file, mustrun.txt, and I update that list by running findincompletefolders.sh.

My question to the experienced programmers is:
How would you structure a submission script that queries this mustrun.txt and launches six calculations off that list, checks to see (via ps) if any of the six directories are done being operated on, re-runs the complete-ness tester, and then starts running the calculation program on a new directory listed in mustrun.txt ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you for your help and inspiration!

EDIT:
Here is what I have pieced together today:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#BSUB -L /bin/bash -W 96:00 -n 20 -R span[ptile=20] -J SET -e tempeoSET -o tempeoSET

cd $TMPDIR
mkdir $TMPDIR/n1
mkdir $TMPDIR/n2
mkdir $TMPDIR/n3
mkdir $TMPDIR/n4
mkdir $TMPDIR/n5
mkdir $TMPDIR/n6
echo

selecteddir1="/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/${unfinishedz[$RANDOM % ${#unfinishedz[@]} ]}"
sleep 4
selecteddir2="/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/${unfinishedz[$RANDOM % ${#unfinishedz[@]} ]}"
sleep 4
selecteddir3="/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/${unfinishedz[$RANDOM % ${#unfinishedz[@]} ]}"
sleep 4
selecteddir4="/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/${unfinishedz[$RANDOM % ${#unfinishedz[@]} ]}"
sleep 4
selecteddir5="/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/${unfinishedz[$RANDOM % ${#unfinishedz[@]} ]}"
sleep 4
selecteddir6="/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/${unfinishedz[$RANDOM % ${#unfinishedz[@]} ]}"

eval cd $selecteddir1
date >> mylog
/scratch/user/myname/program400/program $TMPDIR/n1 &
sleep 4
eval cd $selecteddir2
date >> mylog
/scratch/user/myname/program400/program $TMPDIR/n2 &
sleep 4
eval cd $selecteddir3
date >> mylog
/scratch/user/myname/program400/program $TMPDIR/n3 &
sleep 4
eval cd $selecteddir4
date >> mylog
/scratch/user/myname/program400/program $TMPDIR/n4 &
sleep 4
eval cd $selecteddir5
date >> mylog
/scratch/user/myname/program400/program $TMPDIR/n5 &
sleep 4
eval cd $selecteddir6
date >> mylog
/scratch/user/myname/program400/program $TMPDIR/n6

watch -n 500 '
runningcount=`ps -elf |grep -c program`
if [[ $runningcount --eq 7 ]];
then
sleep 300
.
else
find /scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/z* -type d -amin +0.0001|uniq | sed -e 's_/_ _g'|awk '{print $5}' > /scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/tempz
grep -o -c Complete /scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/z*/Completion.log | awk -F: '{if ($2 < 2){print$1}}'|uniq | sed -e 's_/_ _g'|awk '{print $5}' >> /scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/tempz
sort /scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/tempz|uniq -cd|awk '{print $2}' > /scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/unfinishedz
unfinishedz=($(cat /scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/unfinishedz))
RANDOM=$$$(date +%s)
selecteddir1="/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/"/scratch/user/myname/PROJECT/${unfinishedz[$RANDOM % ${#unfinishedz[@]} ]}""
runningcount=`ps -elf |grep -c program`
cd $selecteddir1
#date >> mylog
/scratch/user/myname/program400/program $TMPDIR/n1 &
.
'

echo
echo working directory
pwd
echo
echo files in directory
ls -l *
echo

exit
```

The loop at the end seems to fail. I am not sure if the loop itself is the issue or other things above it. When I submit this job, 6 random directories do indeed go.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [`parallel -j 6`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/).

Answer (score 0):

What about using the double ampersand && ?

This way you can sequentially execute command.

You can group these commands in parentheses () to preserve the asynchronous execution.

As an extra && checks if the previous command exited with a 'ok' exit code. If you don't want this you can use a semicolon ; instead.

Something like this ?

```
(execute program on dir1/input && execute something next) &
```

Maybe make it even more clever with a while loop. I don't exactly how that would look in your case. But this while loop loops until the inside command returns false (in bash 1 = false, 0 = true).

```
while [ $? -eq 0]; do execute `next_incomplete`; done
```

($?: returns the exit code of the last executed command)